# Transactions and entity groups

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Let me try and describe the requirement.

My product has many sites, each sites have many warehouses, and each warehouse has a count of a important resource it is responsible for.

Whenever someone wants that resource, I want to efficiently pick a (site, warehouse) which will fulfill the requirement (based on some heuristics.)

I reckon I need a transaction over such a operation (as I do not want to leave things in a messy state.)

I have gone over the documentation many times and understand that entity groups are the recommended way of doing transactions.

From Google AppEngine Go documentation:

> An entity's parent, parent's parent, and so on recursively, are its ancestors; its children, children's children, and so on, are its descendants. An entity and its descendants are said to belong to the same entity group.

If I make it so that each warehouse has a site as an ancestor, I can get good control when operating on warehouses under the same site (i.e. entity group.)

What is the simple approach of making the operation safe across all sites and their warehouses?

Approaches I have thought of:

- Make all sites under a virtual parent, but does that allow me to operate on W1 (a warehouse under site S1) and W2 (a warehouse under site S2) transactionally? In other words, are W1 and W2 in one entity group because their own ancestors have the same parent?
- Make all warehouses under a virtual parent, and take the compromise as then all the warehouses are in the same entity group.

Is it just me or the meaning of entity group slightly up for interpretation as per the docs?

PS: The number of such safe operations required is relatively low, so I am not too worried about the limited write throughput of having things under one entity group.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is yes, entities belong to the same group if they have the same parent, even if that parent is a grand-parent for one or both of these entities:

> Every entity with a given root entity as an ancestor is in the same
>   entity group.
>
> From: [Transactions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions)

Comment: So an entity group always starts from a root entity (which has no parent) and encompasses ALL its descendants?

Comment: Also, which of the two approached do you recommend give the above stated fact?

Comment: Yes, so you have to be careful not to include too many entities in a group, where performance limitations will kick in. As for the transactions, you have to examine your use cases carefully. Commits to the datastore fail extremely rarely, so look for use cases where there is a real damage (e.g. transferring money from one account to another). You can also use a Task API to process some requests as it gives you control over re-tries. I cannot help you choose a solution because I don't know the expected loads and potential damages from failed commits.